# Placing a window after TOPMOST window

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7, z-order, window-position

I have a window which is TOPMOST and I have another (myWindow) window which I want to place behind the 1st one and I don't want the second window to be top most:

```
SetWindowPos(topMostWin, HWND_TOPMOST, left, top, width, height, flags);
LONG_PTR exstyle = ::GetWindowLongPtr(myWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE);
if (exstyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST)
{
    exstyle &= ~WS_EX_TOPMOST;
    if( ! ::SetWindowLongPtr(myWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle))
    {
        LOG_ERROR();
    }
}
SetWindowPos(myWindow, topMostWin, left, top, width, height, flags);
```

But myWindow keep acting like top most window and when I check myWindow's `WS_EX_TOPMOST` property of the extended styles it is still turned on. Is it possible to turn off the top most bit even though I'm placing the window after a top most window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HWND_TOP will put your window at the top of the z-order behind any topmost windows.

Comment: I don't want my window to be behind any topmost windows. I want it to be after a specific topmost window but without itself being topmost (WS_EX_TOPMOST property turned off)

Comment: @sanich you can't have a window behind some topmost windows but not others, unless that window is itself topmost.

Comment: OK now I understand. Actually this is what I asked in my question: "Is it possible to turn off the top most bit even though I'm placing the window after a top most window?" Thanks!

Comment: Actually `HWND_NOTOPMOST` will put the window at the top of the z-order behind any topmost windows. `HWND_TOP ` Places the window at the top of the Z order. Please update your answer and add the fact that you wrote in the comment and I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @sanich no, HWND_TOP does that too.

Comment: @Sanich, as i understand, your question is { `is it possible to put a window(X) behind a specific topmost window(Y)  regardless of Window(X)'s WS_EX_TOPMOST property  (what ever can be set or not)?` }

Comment: @JonathanPotter `HWND_TOP` - Places the window at the top of the Z order (meaning at the top of ALL windows (also top most windows).

Comment: @milevyo No. My question was is it possible to put window(x) after topmost window (Y) without setting the WS_EX_TOPMOST property to `true`. The answer is NOT. Because when you place X after  Y OS automatically turns   X's WS_EX_TOPMOST  to 'true'.

Comment: @Sanich, there are two groups of window in zorder view. the top most and normal windows.  setting or unsetting WS_EX_TOPMOST flag, moves window to one of those groups. but HWND_TOP just put that window on top of its siblings from the same group.

Comment: @milevyo Please see the documentation:[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Sanich HWND_TOP does not make a window topmost. This is all in the documentation for SetWindowPos, please read it.

Comment: @Sanich, it is best explained here [the old new thing blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051121-10/?p=33263)

Answer (score 1):

> As a result of the introduction of “topmost” windows, HWND_TOP now brings 
>   the window “as high in the Z-order as possible without violating the
>   rule that topmost windows always appear above non-topmost windows”.
>   What does this mean in practice?
>
> - If a window is topmost, then HWND_TOP puts it at the very top of the Z-order.
> - If a window is not topmost, then HWND_TOP puts it at the top of all non-topmost windows (i.e., just below the lowest topmost window,
>         if any).
>
> Note: The above discussion completely ignores the issue of owner and
>   owned windows. I left them out because they would add a layer of
>   complication that distracts from the main topic.

```
                                *Raymond Chen - The Old New Thing*
```

[link to Raymond's blog site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/)

**what is left to say? ...**